# Displaying List elements in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am passing a list to the view from Controller. How can i generate the following type of HTML by using the Model passed....... 
[image].

I tried using the following code, but it generates a vertical list whereas i want it to be horizontal as well as vertical. Here's my code. How will you write your's to achieve an output like above

```
@foreach (var cats in Model)
{
    <li>@cats.CategoryName</li>
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to combine this mark-up with some css:

```
<ul class="two-columns clearfix">
@foreach (var cats in Model)
{
    <li>@subcats.CategoryName</li>
}
</ul>
```

Then the CSS:

```
ul.two-columns li
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Clear Fix */
.clearfix:after
{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}


* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Comment: Thanks mate...Actually i am very unknown to HTML and CSS since i was working with ASP.NET where i was not exposed to these things :-)

Comment: It worked like a gem but i have no idea how :P . Where can i learn this stuff ?

Comment: I visited W3Schools website and learned everything about CSS from [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). Thanks mate. Your code made me go through all the tutorials in the CSS section. Now I know how things are working.

Comment: This one actually helped me. But I am still trying to figure out how I can divide columns vertically i.e. first column with : Col1, Col2, Col3; Second Column with: Col4, Col5, Col6; Third Column with: Col7, Col8,Col9. I thought about creating three different divs and dividing element based on current element index i.e. (0 - n/3), (n/3 - 2n/3), (2n/3 - n)